# Ember.js: TypeError: _ember2.default.String is undefined (ember s)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I got this problem when run:

> ember s

I don't know what is the origin of the problem. 
The application are run but the page blank and I got this error cited below on browser console.

My versions:

> ```
> ember-cli: 2.13.1
> http_parser: 2.7.0
> node: 4.7.2
> v8: 4.5.103.43
> uv: 1.9.1
> zlib: 1.2.8
> ares: 1.10.1-DEV
> icu: 57.1
> modules: 46
> openssl: 1.0.2g
> os: linux x64
> ```

See the problem at the browser console:

```
08:10:48.807 TypeError: _ember2.default.String is undefined[Learn More] index.js:25
exports.default/< http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86554:11
forEach self-hosted:282:13
exports.default http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86539:5
<anonymous> http://localhost:4200/assets/lisweb-cli.js:79:4     
Module.prototype.exports http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:119:18  
requireModule http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:34:7
<anonymous> http://localhost:4200/assets/lisweb-cli.js:18664:3
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a compatibility problem and downgrade some things temporary solved the problem.